# Web services callback parameters

Tags: c#, web-services

My code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServicesCallBack
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void mServiceTermine();
}


[ServiceContract(CallbackContract=typeof(IServicesCallBack))]
public interface IServices
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void mService(string s);
}
```

I need to get the parameter **(string s)** in the callback (same as main function).

**J2EE platform use mService(string s) to send information to middleware.
C# client implement IServicesCallBack in the middleware to get the callback but i need the s param in the callback.**

Anyone know how to get them in the callback function?

Solution:
***´OperationContext.GetCallbackChannel()´ to get the callback channel. Then you would call ´callbackChannel.mServiceTermine(s);***

Comment: Change your callback function to accept a string parameter. The 's' parameter is available in the "mService" call. Inside the mService call you would use ´OperationContext.GetCallbackChannel<IServicesCallback>()´ to get the callback channel. Then you would call ´callbackChannel.mServiceTermine(s);´

Comment: mService(string s) is called by a j2ee platform. so i don't think it is possible to use OperationContext? , Yes i add more info, sec please

Comment: Added some informations.

Comment: If there's a J2EE client calling your service, it is also the one that needs to implement the callback. From our service perspective, it doesn't matter what implementation is calling us. It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. The client calling the mService, is also the client that expect the callback. Otherwise it's not a callback scenario, but starts to sound like an observer pattern.

Comment: ´OperationContext.GetCallbackChannel<IServicesCallback>()´ to get the callback channel. Then you would call ´callbackChannel.mServiceTermine(s);. Work. thanks marvin.